# Why UsbAccessory class is added in API Level 12 not from API level 8?

Tags: java, android, api, usb, file-transfer

I think most of the world today uses API level 8 and most of the programmers Developes application for API level 8, then why USB functionality not given here is it something special about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the USB functionality relies on software that is installed on the phones.
This means if a phone is only running Froyo (Api Level 8) all the base classes and the usb stuff like drivers etc. is not installed on the phone.

Therefore it can not be used by apps. The users of this phones have to wait for their manufacturers to get an update ready that includes all the USB related stuff and all the other new things that are build in Honeycomb/Ice Cream Sandwich and release it to the devices.

Comment: Thanks for the detail @Janusz but could you more eloberate on first part. i didnt get what exactly you are trying to say. sorry!!

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to ask Google Android developers why that is so, but it is probably that the functionality wasn't developed at the time API level 8 was frozen.  Something as complex as Android takes a lot of people a lot of time to develop.  It can't be done in one go.

But at the end of the day, "why" is not really a question whose answer will help you develop Android apps.

Comment: Thats exactly write Stephen. could you suggest me any guide to do that for API level 8 it would be much helpfull to me. thank you in advance.

Comment: The simple solution is to wait for your device manufacturer to release an version of Android that supports USB.  From what I can tell, many manufacturers offer downloads of USB drivers, but from what I can tell they need to be installed on device by hand, which is not acceptable if you developing an app for end-users to install from an appstore.